# OpenCV + OS X + external webcam = very slow

Tags: python, macos, performance, opencv, webcam

I'm using openCV on OS X with my external webcam (Microsoft Cinema HD Lifecam) and its performance is very low even with the simplest camera readout code.

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow("Output", frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I tried the same webcam with Photo Booth and it works well with high FPS. Also, I tried the same code with the built-in Facetime camera of my mac and it worked pretty fast. So, it seems like that I have some kind of configuration issue in OpenCV.

Has somebody ever experienced something like this? 
Thanks for your answers.

Comment: What is *"high FPS"* and what is *"very slow"* please? Also, in your comments on Ivan's answer, what takes 6.2s? One frame? What takes 11.4s? One frame? How did you install OpenCV?

Answer (score 4):

It seems like I could solve my problem.
I just had to decrease the resolution of the camera.

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(3,640)
cap.set(4,480)
```

I think Photo Booth sets the resolution automatically in order to increase the speed or the readout, however, one has to set this manually in OpenCV. Not sure about correctness of this explanation tough.

Answer (score 0):

Try to enforce specific reader implementation, see [here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#a5d5f5dacb77bbebdcbfb341e3d4355c1). Options to try CAP_QT and CAP_AVFOUNDATION, full list is [here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d4/d15/group__videoio__flags__base.html#ga023786be1ee68a9105bf2e48c700294d) . Note, that OpenCV has to be built to support reader implementations.

Comment: 6.2s with the built-in webcam
11.4s with the external one